# cannot load the Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I wanted to use my app on a new computer so I pulled everything from Git and relaunch `composer`and `yarn`to get all my third-parthy bundles and lib.

When running the `composer update`I get the following error :

> Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\BlogPostRepository": argument "$registry" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry" instead.

With my `BlogRepository being

```php
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\BlogPost;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method BlogPost|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method BlogPost|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method BlogPost[]    findAll()
 * @method BlogPost[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class BlogPostRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, BlogPost::class);
    }
}
```

It has been auto-generated by symfony and I never changed it. Is it a bug or does the `composer-update`changed everything ?

Comment: It's not so much that update changes everything but this particular transition was not handled very well.  A search would reveal that lots of developers have run into this.  Just make the suggested change in all your repos and things should be back to normal.

Comment: Have you made sure that you are using the same versions of your dependencies on both systems?

Comment: no it's not, that's why it was working on the previous machine. But I posted a solution (that has been downvoted for no reason...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is deprecated since August as shown in this [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/32394) my bad

As suggested in the `error` we now need to use the parent Interface :

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
```